# Documentation have also been un-shipped

Tags: bug, documentation, old-teams, stack-overflow-business

The old [teams page](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) describes that one of the current efforts is Documentation:

> Our resources are currently allocated on projects to enhance and improve quality on Q&A, Documentation, and Jobs on Stack Overflow, as a result we don’t have the dedicated developers to get Teams to its fullest potential.

Well, it's not true anymore, maybe we should rephrase it in a more future-proof way.

Comment: Maybe they’re still secretly dedicating resources to Documentation :)

Comment: @JF If they are, they should write it down in a formal place where we can read it somewhere.

Comment: With the even newer teams page, that's not an issue anymore.